# insert transparent image to pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I load my image to the pdf in the following way:

```
PDImageXObject image= PDImageXObject.createFromFile(<image_path>, doc);
contentStream.drawImage(image, 15, pdfData.getPageHeight() - 80,
image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
```

I'm trying to make the image look transparent, like it would look in a header of a document(google docs, word etc.)
is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an extended graphics state:

```
stream.saveGraphicsState();
PDExtendedGraphicsState pdExtGfxState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
pdExtGfxState.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.BM, COSName.MULTIPLY); // pdExtGfxState.setBlendMode(BlendMode.MULTIPLY) doesn't work yet, maybe in later version 
pdExtGfxState.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant(0.5f);
contentStream.setGraphicsStateParameters(pdExtGfxState);
// do your stuff
stream.restoreGraphicsState();
```